# What does *^ mean?

Tags: syntax

I've come across some code, for instance, from the question,
[Passing a function and its derivative to a module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128694/passing-a-function-and-its-derivative-to-a-module)

```
   Mean[l[NestList[f[#, μ] &, 0.1, 1*^2]]]
```

What does the 1*^2 mean?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I can't believe I spent so much time searching for what it was, rather than just typing to see what it did.

Comment: `a*^b` is interpreted as $a\times 10^b$, i.e "scientific notation".

Comment: See [Input Syntax - Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977). I'll admit that it's harder to find in the docs than I expected!

Comment: **General FYI**: someone flagged a comment here as being factually incorrect.  This is not a valid reason to raise a moderator flag, as moderators should not be passing judgement on what is correct or incorrect.  Rather you should comment yourself and voice your objection.